# Best way to filter table in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have an array of objects stored in redux. I want to be able to filter that array based on user input. Should I create a state object that receives the array through props and modify that array, or is it bad practice to mix state and props? If it is alright to mix the two, should I set the state in componentWillReceiveProps?

Comment: todomvc is very logical approach to follow for filtering state. here's what it looks like with react/redux https://github.com/reactjs/redux/blob/master/examples/todomvc/components/MainSection.js

Comment: I'm looking more for something like this https://facebook.github.io/fixed-data-table/example-filter.html, except I'm receiving the array through props instead of having it as my state.

Comment: Exactly the same principle applies though. Remember, your props are someone else's state. You store your user input as state somewhere.. either redux or in the table component, then filter your props array against that filter state.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Building state based on props can be somewhat complicated, which is acceptable, but you should consider all of your options.

The simplest to implement is to filter the props in your `render` method. If you have sufficiently small components which don't update for too many reasons, and especially if the number of elements in the list is low, this might be the preferred method:

```
class FilterList extends React.Component {
  render () {
    const { elements } = this.props;
    const { filterStr } = this.state;

    const filteredElements = elements
      .filter(e => e.includes(filterStr))
      .map(e => <li>{ e }</li>)

    return (
      <div>
        <input
          type="text"
          value={ filterStr }
          onChange={ e => this.setState({ filterStr: e.target.value }) } />
        <ul>
          { filteredElements }
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

The next option is to do what you're describing, and derive a computed state based of the component's filter state and props passed to it. This is good when you have a complicated component which recieves many props and is rendered often. Here, you're caching the viewable elements and only filtering the list when it needs to be filtered.

```
class FilterList extends React.Component {
  constructor (props) {
    this.state = {
      viewableEls: props.elements
    }
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps (nextProps) {
    const { elements } = this.props;
    const { filterStr } = this.state;

    if (elements !== nextProps.elements) {
      this.setState({
        viewableEls: this.getViewableEls(nextProps.elements, filterStr)
      })
    }
  }

  getViewableEls (elements, filterStr) {
    return elements.filter(el => el.includes(filterStr))
  }

  handleFilterChange = e => {
    const { elements } = this.props;

    this.setState({
      filterStr: e.target.value,
      viewableEls: this.getViewableEls(elements, filterStr)
    })
  }
  render () {
    const { viewableEls } = this.state;

    return (
      <div>
        <input
          type="text"
          value={ filterStr }
          onChange={ this.handleFilterChange } />
        <ul>
          { viewableEls.map(e => <li key={ e }>{ e }</li>) }
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

And finally, the redux 'way', which requires you to pass the action creator and `filterStr` as props to the component, probably passed in via `connect` somewhere else. The implementation below is using a stateless component since we're not keeping the `fitlerStr` in the component state at all.

```
const FilterTable = ({ elements, filterStr, changeFilterStr }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <input
        type="text"
        value={ filterStr }
        onChange={ e => changeFilterStr(e.target.value) } />
      <ul>
        {
          elements
            .filter(e => e.includes(filterStr))
            .map(e => <li key={ e }>{ e }</li>)
        }
      </ul>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Thanks for putting in the time to answer the question in depth!

Comment: The first and third examples are quite good. I must however take issue with the second example. Your `this.state.viewableEls` is derived entirely from props and state, whereas state fields should really contain unique pieces of information. You claim this has a caching benefit, but I don't see it; since a render is only triggered when props/state update anyway.

Comment: In the contrived example, you're correct, there is no benefit to 'caching`, but if you are receiving other props which trigger `render`, but which shouldn't affect the value of `this.state.viewableEls`, then there is. Unless I'm misunderstanding you, of course. Lets say 90% of the re-renders are triggered by the change of a prop which `viewableEls` isn't a function of (lets say there is a real-time chat component which is a child), and `elements` is in the range of tens of thousands of elements, there will be non-trivial but unncessary re-calulation every time a new message comes through. No?

Comment: gave you a +1 for the redux part, instead of managing two list within store, only keep one and keep filter/order items

Comment: in the second example how are you using `handleFilterChange` function?

Comment: Huh, not sure why i left unused... Fixing now

Comment: Do you have any advice for an advanced filtering library in React? For instance, if I had rows of unstructured data, or if I wanted to render different controls? Checkboxes vs drop downs for instance? My first thoughts are to use React Grid, hide columns, and put a bulma card in one column per row.